# unique_handle<T, Traits> wrapper for memory and other resources

Tags: memory-management, c++03

There is a good article on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/%20magazine/hh288076) about creating a RAII class `unique_handle` that owns resources and releases them when deleted. See the source code below:

```
template <typename Type, typename Traits>
class unique_handle
{
  unique_handle(unique_handle const &);
  unique_handle & operator=(unique_handle const &);
  void close() throw()
  {
    if (*this)
    {
      Traits::close(m_value);
    }
  }
  Type m_value;
public:
  explicit unique_handle(Type value = Traits::invalid()) throw() :
    m_value(value)
  {
  }
  ~unique_handle() throw()
  {
    close();
  }
}
```

I want to create an instance of this `unique_handle` and store it in a collection such as `vector` or `list`. The problem is that the collections require a stored class to have a copy constructor. `vector` needs `operator=` to move objects in memory.

Then the author adds move constructor as below that solves the above requirements in C++11:

```
unique_handle(unique_handle && other) throw() :
  m_value(other.release())
{
}
unique_handle & operator=(unique_handle && other) throw()
{
  reset(other.release());
  return *this;
}
```

My question is how can I use this class with collections if C++11 is not available. I have C++03. I know that boost has `unique_ptr` that works in previous versions of C++ and can be stored in collections but it's very complex and requires a lot of headers. I am not sure if I can use boost in my project. Are there other alternative solutions?

Comment: `unique_ptr` can be easily backported to C++03 projects. You can google around for Howard Hinnart's backport (I have [this link](https://github.com/SRombauts/unique_ptr) but I hear there is an improved version, links to which I can not find), it is very easy to integrate to existing toolkits, as I have done with my overall [backports toolkit](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/home). The original version actually depended on Boost, but also was pretty easy to deBoostify.

Comment: Thanks for the links. backport toolkit looks interesting. I will test if its `unique_ptr` works for me.